# How to get OSM data for different areas at once?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, quickosm

I am trying to get some OSM data (schools, shops, public transport stops etc.) for several cities. I have a shp-boundaries for cities.

I use QuickOSM for QGIS or overpass-turbo on a Web. I have a query for data but I can't figure out how to automatize extraction for different bounding boxes at once. For now I select bounding box every time manually :(

Answer (score 3):

In overpass-turbo you can [union](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Union) search areas, like [this](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/o51) (pharmacies in Bielsko-Biala, Żywiec and Pszczyna)

Comment: Thank you, it looks almost what I want. But I can't use OSM city boundaries (they not match ours) so I tried to use spatial extent instead of geocoded area in your request but failed.

Comment: What do you mean with *I tried to use spatial extent*? How does that relate to your overpass query? You can also provide boundaries on your own by specifying a list of lat/lon values via `(poly: )` filter.

Answer (score 1):

In QuickOSM, in the field `in` you can specify many areas separated with a semicolon, for instance, you can write: `bangkok;paris;london'

You can also make QuickOSM automated using the processing modeler: 
[image: QGIS Processing Modeler]

You need to go to `Processing` -> `Graphical modeler`. Then you can find some algorithms provided by QuickOSM. I agree it takes some time to understand QuickOSM algorithms.

Can you tell us more about your query? Do you want to loop over you shp-boundaries for each request?

Comment: Thank you, from time to time I have a task to download an OSM data for different let say regions (actually it is cities but with a little bit different from the OSM data boundary). One time it can be schools, shops, hospitals and some other social objects for 15 cities another time it can be pedestrian roads for 10 cities. I have already a request for QuickOSM to union all OSM data I want to download at once. But I don't know how to union different bboxes. All cities boundaries stored at one shp file and I want to process my QuickOSM request for each selected feature (city boundary) at once.